# Writing a device tree (dts) overlay for an enc28j60 chip on the amlogic meson g12a platform

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, spi, device-tree, soc

I need to write a `.dts` overlay file to use a Microchip `enc28j60` on a `Radxa Zero`, which is an `Amlogic Meson G12A` platform via `SPI`. The kernel I'm using is [5.10 from radxa](https://github.com/radxa/kernel/tree/linux-5.10.y-radxa-zero).

Starting from having absolutely no idea what I was doing, I have ended up with the following overlay:

```c
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

#include <dt-bindings/interrupt-controller/irq.h>
#include <dt-bindings/gpio/meson-g12a-gpio.h>

&spicc1 {
    // spicc1 defined in meson-g12-common.dtsi

    // See meson-g12a-spi-spidev.dts
    pinctrl-0 = <&spicc1_pins &spicc1_ss0_pins>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    // handled by `param_spidev_spi_bus` and meson-fixup.scr-cmd for the spi-spidev overlay
    status = "okay";

    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;

    eth1: enc28j60@0 {
        compatible = "microchip,enc28j60";
        reg = <0>;  /* for spi, this defines the chipselect */
        /**
         * gpio_int has interrupts-cells = <2>
         *
         * How does this distinguish between e.g. GPIOAO_4 on the first chip and GPIOZ_4 on the second ?!
         */
        interrupt-parent = <&gpio_intc>;
        interrupts = <GPIOX_8 IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_FALLING>;

        // causes "enc28j60 spi1.0: there is not valid maps for state default"
        pinctrl-0 = <&enc28j60_int_pin>;
        pinctrl-names = "default";

        spi-max-frequency = <12000000>;
        status = "okay";
        debug = <1>;
    };
};

// See meson-g12-common.dtsi
// I think what happens here is that we define this pin as the interrupt pin (something must
// tell the chip that we want this pin to receive interrupts) and then "interrupts" in &eth1
// actually uses it
&periphs_pinctrl {
    enc28j60_int_pin: enc28j60_int_pin@0 {
        amlogic,pins = <&gpio GPIOX_8>;
        amlogic,function = <0>; /* in */
        amlogic,pull = <IRQ_TYPE_NONE>;
    };
};

// Not entirely sure this is correct, but I haven't found any other way to do this
// and this compiles
/ {
    __overrides__ {
        irq   = <&eth1>, "interrupts:0", <&enc28j60_int_pin>, "brcm,pins:0";
        speed = <&eth1>, "spi-max-frequency:0";
    };
};
```

The result of my efforts, unfortunately is still a non-functioning `enc28j60` driver:

```sh
[    3.882872] enc28j60 spi1.0: there is not valid maps for state default
[    3.884022] enc28j60 spi1.0: Ethernet driver 1.02 loaded
[    3.896540] enc28j60 spi1.0: chip not found
[    3.896686] enc28j60: probe of spi1.0 failed with error -5
```

I have documented the entire process and progress (or lack thereof) on the [Radxa Community Forums](https://forum.radxa.com/t/using-an-enc28j60-on-the-zero/9348).

What I would need to progress are either information (but I'll gladly accept answers to all of the questions ;)):

1. How to put the kernel and driver into debug mode so that I can see
   more detailed information than what `dmesg` is outputting above.
2. How to verify what I am trying to do with the interrupt pin is correct
   and making sense. (I have found similar examples for other platforms
   [`tegra`, `brcm`], but for the meson chips, `pinctrl` seems to be
   entirely done as part of the kernel driver code, not as a device
   tree).

Comment: First message tells you that the pin muxing hadn't happened. Then it can't find chip by one or another from many reasons. The last one tells you the actual error code https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h#L9. So, you may look into the code and figure out which line failed.

Comment: I am unfortunately unable to figure out what is wrong about the pinmux/pinctrl or how it should be configured.

Comment: To give a brief update on this issue. We have determined that there is a problem with the SPI implementation of the Amlogic Meson G12A as mentioned by kernel developer Neil Armstrong and our understanding of the matter is insufficient to determine whether or not it can be made to work. [Detailed information in this post](https://forum.radxa.com/t/using-an-enc28j60-on-the-zero/9348/18).